# PHP not allowing ACCESS update on certain columns

Tags: php, ms-access

I am trying to update records in my legacy access system via php, but on certain columns it isn't working. For example the below works :

```
$query = "UPDATE Valuations SET SalesParticulars = '" . $salesparticulars . "',
 Company = '" . $company . "' WHERE Ref=" . $ref;
```

If I change "Company" to "Name" it doesn't work, even though name is just a column in the database exactly the same as Company.

Basically I can update "Company" but not "Name", even though they are both the same data types

I get this exception, how can I catch it?

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '**Source:** Microsoft Access Database Engine
> **Description:** Syntax error in UPDATE statement.' in

This is my full code

```
// Create an instance of the ADO connection object
$conn = new COM ("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO");

// Define the connection string and specify the database driver
$connStr = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=".realpath("HS_BE.accdb").";";

// Open the connection to the database
$conn->open($connStr);
$name= "gareth";
// Declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = "UPDATE Valuations SET SalesParticulars = '" . $salesparticulars . "',
 Name = '" . $name . "'
 WHERE Ref=" . $ref;

echo $query;

// Execute the SQL statement and return records
$rs = $conn->execute($query);
```

Comment: Did you try to run the same query in MS Access directly? Does it work?

Comment: @user4035 yeah it does, strange

Comment: Is there a way to get the error after executing the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because *Name* is a reserved word in Access SQL.

You can wrap it in brackets like this:

```
$query = "UPDATE Valuations SET SalesParticulars = '" . $salesparticulars . "',
 [Name] = '" . $name . "' WHERE Ref=" . $ref;
```